# Any point in using LIMIT in EXISTS query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, exists, sql-limit

Is there any performance benefit in adding a `LIMIT` to an `EXISTS` query, or would MySQL apply the limit on its own?

Example:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM my_table
     LIMIT 1    -- can this improve performance?
)
THEN ... END IF;
```

Comment: yeah ...This improve performance because you are limiting records.

Comment: Have you tried using `EXPLAIN` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes, it doesn't seem affected.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, there are many rows in `my_table`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @AbhishekGinani I don't think so. SQL is smart enough to do only what's needed. It stops once it finds ANY record. That's the purpose of it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The purpose of `EXISTS()` is to perform the query *only until* it can decide if there are *any* rows in that table matching the `WHERE` clause.  That is, it logically does the same thing as `LIMIT 1`.  `EXISTS` is probably called `semi-join` in some circles.

Bottom line:  Don't use `LIMIT 1` inside `EXISTS()`.

Addenda:  As Paul points out, a `LIMIT` *with* an `OFFSET` (or `LIMIT m,n`) does have meaning.

Comment: LIMIT seems to be ignored in an EXISTS subquery. But you would need it, if you want to define an OFFSET, when you want to check if at least N rows exist.

Answer (score 3):

Fiddling with my query a bit, I noticed that `EXISTS` still returns 1 if `LIMIT` is set to 0. I assume this indicates that it's being ignored.

Comment: I suggest that `LIMIT 0` is an aberrant edge case.

Comment: It is a proof of concept case

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how many records in your table(my_table).If records are not too much then you will not see any performance improvement but if your table has too much records then you will see the performance improvement but this will also depends on many factor as do you have index in the column those are being used in select(if you will do this then you will get the benefit of covering index also).

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since the question was submitted. In case anyone needs a workaround, I am posting a solution.

As discussed above, the limit is dismissed in EXISTS block. However, if we use a subquery as the main query of the EXISTS, we can apply the LIMIT to the subquery. In this case, the subquery is working like a LATERAL that provides the data for the condition.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    your_table AS outer_table
WHERE
    ...
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            1
        FROM (
            -- This subquery is working as a LATERAL, so follow the same structure.
            SELECT
                condition_row
            FROM
                inner_table
            WHERE
                ...
                -- Make sure the subquery is referencing the required entries. (for example if the result blunges to the same account)
                AND inner_table.reference=outer_table.reference
            -- If applying any ordering.
            ORDER BY inner_events.ordering_row ASC
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS subquery
        where
            -- Check if the rest of the EXISTS condition here.
            your_condition=subquery.condition_row
    );
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @shmosel The above is an example of using a LIMIT within an EXISTS. One example I have encountered is optimizing a query that uses a LATERAL subquery that is required to check if the first entry order by creation date is within a condition or not. Hope this explanation helps to clarify the use.